# How do I get numerical data while web scraping?

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I'm completely new to web scraping, so any reference sites would be great. I am slightly confused as to how I'm getting the actual data. When I print(theText), I get a bunch of html code (which should be correct). How do I exactly go about getting values from this? Do I have to use regular expressions to get the actual numerical data?

```
def getData():
    request = urllib.request.Request("http://www.weather.com/weather/5day/l/USGA0028:1:US")
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    the_page = response.read()
    theText = the_page.decode()
    print(theText)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). It allows you to get elements by their IDs or tags. It is very useful for basic scraping.
You can just call beutiful soup with the response text (html page) and then you can call the bs methods

Comment: Thank you for the website! I am, however, doing a homework assignment which requires the use of regex. This is the reason why I'm having a lot of trouble finding a website to explain the basics.

Comment: this should help for python https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html  
this for regular expressions in general http://regexone.com/

Answer (score 0):

no, you [shouldn't use RegExp for HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).
Instead. Have a look at [BeatifulSoup4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: Thanks! I am, however, doing a homework assignment which requires the use of regex. This is the reason why I'm having a lot of trouble finding a website to explain the basics.